# XStream -> ConversionException: null : null. Нужна подсказка.

Tags: java, xml

Имеется xml с данными:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ipm>
<isomsg>
  <field id="24" value="697"/>
  <isomsg id="48">
    <isomsg id="105">
      <field id="1" value="222"/>
      <field id="2" value="3333"/>
    </isomsg>
  </isomsg>
</isomsg>
  <isomsg>
  <field id="0" value="222"/>
    <isomsg id="3">
      <field id="1" value="00"/>
      <field id="2" value="00"/>
      <field id="3" value="00"/>
    </isomsg>
  </isomsg>
</ipm>
```

классы

```
public class Field {
    private String id;

    private String value;

    public String getId ()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getValue ()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue (String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class Isomsg {
    private String id;

    private Field[] field;

    public String getId ()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Field[] getField ()
    {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField (Field[] field)
    {
        this.field = field;
    }
}
    public class Ipm {
    private Isomsg[] isomsg;

    public Isomsg[] getIsomsg ()
    {
        return isomsg;
    }

    public void setIsomsg (Isomsg[] isomsg)
    {
        this.isomsg = isomsg;
    }
}
```

я хочу сериализовать в объект

```
 XStream xstream = new XStream();
        xstream.alias("ipm", Ipm.class);
        xstream.alias("isomsg", Isomsg.class);
        Object o = xstream.fromXML(FileManager.getContents(inputXMl.getAbsolutePath()));
```

Получаю

```
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: null : null
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : java.lang.NullPointerException
cause-message       : null
class               : java.lang.reflect.Field
required-type       : java.lang.reflect.Field
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.extended.JavaFieldConverter
path                : /ipm/isomsg/field
line number         : 4
class[1]            : [Ltest.java.main.XmlGenerator.xml.Isomsg;
converter-type[1]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.ArrayConverter
class[2]            : test.java.main.XmlGenerator.xml.Ipm
converter-type[2]   : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
version             : 1.4.7
-------------------------------

    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:79)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.readItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:71)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.ArrayConverter.unmarshal(ArrayConverter.java:55)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:474)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:406)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:257)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1185)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1169)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1040)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:1031)
```

Есть другие аналои сериализации. Детаю по аналогии, но не получается.
Подскажите где я ошибся?

Comment: кажется. что проблема в том, что внутри isomsg  имеется isomsg, а внутри филда - филд

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблема в том, что внутри isomsg имеется isomsg, а внутри филда - филд